# Azure Blob SAS Url returned from API authentication failed .net core

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to return a SAS url to my frontend so I can redirect the user to that link and so they can download the file.

This is my code to create the SAS url

```
   private SasQueryParameters GenerateSaSCredentials(string containerName, string blobName) {


        //  Defines the resource being accessed and for how long the access is allowed.
        BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new() {
            StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)),
            ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120)) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            Resource = "b",
            BlobName = blobName,
            BlobContainerName = containerName
        };
        
        //  Defines the type of permission.
        blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

        //  Builds an instance of StorageSharedKeyCredential      
        StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential = new(_accountName, _key);

        //  Builds the Sas URI.
        return blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(storageSharedKeyCredential);
    }

    public Uri CreateBlobUri(string blobName, string containerName) {
        SasQueryParameters parameters = GenerateSaSCredentials(containerName, blobName);
        
        return new UriBuilder {
            Scheme = "https",
            Host = $"{_accountName}.blob.core.windows.net",
            Path = $"files/{containerName}/{blobName}",
            Query = WebUtility.UrlDecode(parameters.ToString())
        }.Uri;
        
    }
```

You may notice the url decode on parameters.ToString() is because of a similar issue ive seen on stackoverflow where they spoke of double encoding.

However when i return this url to the browser and redirect i get the following error.

This is how i return the URL

```
 return Ok(_blobUtils.CreateBlobUri(fileName, containerName).ToString());
```

```
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header 
  is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:01696cca-d01e-0023-2ea4-74f5df000000 
  Time:2021-07-09T09:23:33.0250817Z</Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

If i remove the WebUtility.UrlDecode from the `parameters.ToString()`, i get this error

```
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header 
  is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:016a1821-d01e-0023-3da4-74f5df000000 
  Time:2021-07-09T09:24:38.4051042Z</Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2021-07- 
 09T09:14:38Z 2021-07-09T11:24:39Z /blob/${_acountName}/files/bqXbY54sRRsipOUB1PF6/fyI67FYOqDS80y1vNWRL/PRE_OP_CT/0/TK1.left.TST.PTN1.PRE 
 _OP_CT.zip 2020-04-08 b </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

The structure of the Blob i am trying to access is:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
And finally the blob we are trying to create a SAS to

[image]

Can anyone see why this would fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please get rid of `files` from `Path` here:

```
return new UriBuilder {
    Scheme = "https",
    Host = $"{_accountName}.blob.core.windows.net",
    Path = $"files/{containerName}/{blobName}",
    Query = WebUtility.UrlDecode(parameters.ToString())
}.Uri;
```

It should be something like:

```
return new UriBuilder {
    Scheme = "https",
    Host = $"{_accountName}.blob.core.windows.net",
    Path = $"{containerName}/{blobName}",
    Query = WebUtility.UrlDecode(parameters.ToString())
}.Uri;
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the screenshot and the error message, the name of your container is `files` and the name of the blob is `bqXbY54sRRsipOUB1PF6/fyI67FYOqDS80y1vNWRL/PRE_OP_CT/0/TK1.left.TST.PTN1.PRE`. Please use them in your code and you should not get the error. You still need to remove `files` from the Path above as it is already included in your `containerName`.

The reason your code is failing is because you're calculating SAS token for a blob inside a blob container (the blob path becomes `container-name/blob-name`). However in your request, you're prepending `files` to your request URL, your blob path becomes `files/container-name/blob-name`. Since the SAS token is obtained for a different path but is used for another path, you're getting the error.

Comment: Hi Gaurav thanks for your response the blob i am looking for is under the containers files, should that still be removed? wouldnt that make the URL invalid as it wont find the recourse

Comment: You mean to say your container name is `files`? The answer is no. Basically your path will be `container-name/blob-name` so it should remain there.

Comment: apologies for confusing you, no the container name is a different value a unique ID in this case but all those are stored under a generic container called files. As what we are storing in there is the company files. I will post a screenshot on my question to clarify the structure

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshots obviously the containerName/blobName in this case of the screenshots would resolve to something like bqXbY54sRRsipOUB1PF6/fyI67FYOqDS80y1vNWRL/PRE_OP_CT/0/TK1.left.TST.PTN1.PRE_OP_CT.zip That is why i added the files/ there

Comment: Thanks will give it a go and let you know but i think you are absolutely right here!

Comment: `bqXbY54sRRsipOUB1PF6/fyI67FYOqDS80y1vNWRL` is not the name of the container. It is the name of the virtual folder. Your container name is `files`.

Comment: Thank you so much man spend 3 days on this thing and you solved it in seconds huge thanks! Really grateful here

Comment: :). You should have come here sooner. I am glad to hear that your problem is solved.